# Not a statement error in Complex Numbers

Tags: java, numbers, textwrangler

```
public String toString ()
{
    String result;

    if (imaginary == 0) 
    {
        return real + " ";
    }
    else if (real == 0)
    {
        return imaginary + "i";
    }
    else (imaginary < 0);
    {
        return real + " - " + (-imaginary) + "i";
    }
    return real + " + " = imaginary + "i";
}
```

}

I am trying to get my code to work, to add, subtract and divide complex numbers. Everything else is compelling correctly but I have one error.

its telling me that my else (imaginary < 0); is incorrect..telling me that it is not a statement

Comment: You have a semicolon after that else block. This probably isn't intentional. Is that it?

Comment: The line should read `else if (imaginary < 0)` (ie, add `if` after `else`, and remove the semicolon). You cannot use a comparison on `else`. `else` means if nothing in the comparisons above was true.

Answer (score 1):

The line that gives you the error should read;

```
else if (imaginary < 0)
```

Add `if` after `else`, and remove the semicolon.

You cannot use a comparison on `else`. It means 'if nothing in the comparisons above was true'.

Comment: I tried that but even more errors occur because of that change. I didn't mean to add the semicolon at the end, thanks for catching that. But adding the if, as I said, gave me a lot more errors. From 1 error to 15.

Comment: More errors aren't always bad. What are the new errors?